# If $p$ is prime, $m$ is composite and deficient, and $I(p) < I(m)$, does it follow that $m < p$, where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, divisor-sum

**PROBLEM STATEMENT (ORIGINAL)**

> If $p$ is prime, $m$ is composite and deficient, and $I(p) < I(m)$, does it follow that $m < p$, where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $$m = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{{q_i}^{\alpha_i}},$$
where $q_1 < \ldots < q_m$ are primes, for some $r = \omega(m) \geq 2$.

Then 
$$I(m) = \prod_{i=1}^{r}{I({q_i}^{\alpha_i})}$$
and we are given that
$$\frac{p+1}{p} = I(p) < I(m).$$
It follows that
$$p > \frac{1}{I(m) - 1} = \frac{1}{\prod_{i=1}^{r}{I({q_i}^{\alpha_i})} - 1} = \bigg(\prod_{i=1}^{r}{I({q_i}^{\alpha_i})} - 1\bigg)^{-1}.$$

I believe that the [Bernoulli Inequality](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/BernoulliInequality.html) does not apply in this case.  This is where I get stuck.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT (REVISED)**

> If $p$ is prime, $m$ is composite and deficient, and $I(p) < I(m)$ with $p \nmid m$, does it follow that $m < p$, where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Note that
$$\frac{1}{I(m) - 1} > m$$
does not hold, as it will imply that $\sigma(m) < m + 1$, contradicting the fact that $m$ is composite.

Comment: $I(5) = 6/5 < 2 = I(6)$?

Comment: Thanks, @eyeballfrog!  I forgot to indicate that $m$ must be deficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it doesn't.

A counterexample is $(p,m)=(2,15)$ where $p\not\mid m, m\gt p$ and
$$\sigma(15)=24\lt 2\times 15,\quad\qquad I(p)=\frac 32\lt \frac{24}{15}=I(m)$$